# MySQL stored procedure caused `Commands out of sync`

Tags: php, mysql

Call procedure works all right in MySQL terminal, but in PHP, caused `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command nowCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

My procedure is

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getMostSimilar (IN vU_ID INT, IN voffset INT, IN vsize INT)
BEGIN
set @offset = voffset;
set @size = vsize;
set @uid = vU_ID;
prepare SimilarStmt from
"SELECT U_ID, getSimilarity(U_ID, ?) AS similar FROM Answer WHERE U_ID != ? GROUP BY U_ID ORDER BY similar DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
execute SimilarStmt using @uid, @uid, @offset, @size; 
deallocate prepare SimilarStmt;
END
$$
```

where getSimilarity is a function.

In PHP:

```
function getMostSimilar($U_ID, $offset, $size){
    $query = sprintf("CALL getMostSimilar(%s, %s, %s)",
                $U_ID, $offset, $size);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    print mysql_error();
    if (!$result){
        return $query;
    }
    $ans = array();
    $len = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $ans[$len] = $row;
        $len++;
    }
    return $ans;
}
```

What should I do now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C.5.2.14. Commands out of sync If you
> get Commands out of sync; you can't
> run this command now in your client
> code, you are calling client functions
> in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you
> are using mysql_use_result() and try
> to execute a new query before you have
> called mysql_free_result(). It can
> also happen if you try to execute two
> queries that return data without
> calling mysql_use_result() or
> mysql_store_result() in between.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

I think you need to rewrite the getMostSimilar stored procedure, instead of using prepare and execute (which I thinks is fooling mysql) if you use the parameters in the procedure like  [in this example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx) I think your error will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've googled this, but it doesn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: I think that the mysql optimizer is interpreting your getMostSimilar function as recursive and wants you to free, use or store the data returns before it will do anything more.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL won't allow variables in the LIMIT clause, so simply rewriting the procedure to do a SELECT won't work

Comment: That's true! So what can I do? @wonk0

Comment: Well, the solution is to do like you did - use a prepared statement (cf. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918). But somehow this does not seem to work with your function getSimilarity() (I guess this will be the reason). Maybe you could post some more information, e.g. table definitions or that function?

Comment: @wonk0, I'm using variables for the LIMIT clause in MySQL SPROCs so what you said is not true.

Comment: @Ovilia - Are stored procedures with multiple queries allowed using plain mysql? I am also getting the same error as you discuss here.

Comment: @wonk0 - Are stored procedures with multiple queries allowed using plain mysql? I am also getting the same error as you discuss here.

Answer (score 16):

There seems to be a nasty bug (or feature) that is manifested when calling a stored procedure that **returns a result set.**. I.e. a stored procedure that ends with a select statement without an INTO clause (see example below).

The mysqli driver (probably) returns 2 result sets. The first is the one returned from the stored procedure and the second a dummy, empty result set. It is like a multiple query command was issued. One solution to this (that does not break on usual (e.g. SELECT) queries), is to consume this dummy result set after processing the legit one (the first).

Example PHP code

```
function do_query($con, $sql)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result === true) {
        return true;
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // process rows
    }
    // Hack for procedures returning second dummy result set
    while (mysqli_more_results($con)) {
        mysqli_next_result($con);
        // echo "* DUMMY RS \n";
    }
}
```

Example stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selectStaleHeaders()
NOT DETERMINISTIC
SELECT TT.*
FROM one_pretty_table AS TT
  LEFT JOIN another AS AN on TT.fk_id = AN.id
WHERE TT.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I had the same problem with a stored procedure ending with a SELECT statement AND using the INTO clause. The reason was because of the datatype of the parameter I was transferring the data into (DECIMAL instead of DECIMAL(10,2)). Changing the datatype fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This "bug" was happening to me with extremely simple procedure even inside phpmyadmin. The reason was that I was declaring general variables (without the @ prefix). I changed my variables to user-defined variables prefixed with @ and it was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same message for a whole different reason, so I will leave my solution here:

It was just a typo in a parameter name.
My function had a parameter named `preferable`:

```
create function call_client (pereferable int, client_id int) returns int
```

In the function body, I was using the parameter `preferable` with the wrong name:

```
if prefered  = 1 then
  ...
end if;
```

Once I changed `prefered` for `preferable` it started working again.