# MySQL command out of sync when using POW()

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query that runs perfectly, until I add the POW function to it. I don't understand why I get this error. I've tried to google it but came up empty for a solution.

Original query:

```
SELECT  86400 /
        (NOW() - `created_at`) *
        (
            (
                SELECT  COUNT(`Votes`.`voteID`)
                FROM    `Votes`
                WHERE   `postID` = `Posts`.`postID`
                LIMIT   1
            )
            + 0
            * 5
        ) AS `rank`
FROM    `Posts`
```

query with POW():

```
SELECT  POW(
            86400 
            / (NOW() - `created_at`) 
            * 
            (
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(`Votes`.`voteID`) 
                    FROM    `Votes` 
                    WHERE   `postID` = `Posts`.`postID` 
                    LIMIT   1
                ) 
                + 0 
                * 5
            ), 
            1.8
        ) AS `rank` 
FROM    `Posts`
```

The error I get is `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: I don't see to which power you are raising it, that might be an issue regardless. As for your actual error, this error occurs when the client and server are out of sync which can have many causes but are usually related to MySQL client bugs (also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6583068/54017)

Comment: I'm raising to 1.8 but indeed, not really relevant. As for the answer you liked too, I don't really see how this could help me since this is all one query...

Comment: The point is that it is either a bug in MySQL or a client bug. It shouldn't be related to your query. If this error is really specific to using `POW()` than it's a MySQL bug. If not than it's a client bug/incompatibility with your MySQL version. Try executing the query using a different client (i.e. straight from the MySQL commandline).

Comment: @CupOfTea696 have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891179/mysql-error-2014-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: You may be exposing a bug in `POW()` by passing it an absurdly large, or non-numeric first argument.  `(NOW() - created_at)` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  You may want `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)` if you hope for a time-difference computation giving a number of seconds as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Ollie Jones' suggestion, which worked perfectly for me!

> You may be exposing a bug in `POW()` by passing it an absurdly large, or non-numeric first argument. `(NOW() - created_at)` probably doesn't do what you think it does. You may want `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)` if you hope for a time-difference computation giving a number of seconds as a result. –  Ollie Jones

Answer (score 0):

While this seems like interesting error in POW() function, you maybe can get around by encapsulating into another subquery:

```
SELECT POW(rank,1.8)
FROM
(
SELECT  (
            86400 
            / (NOW() - `created_at`) 
            * 
            (
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(`Votes`.`voteID`) 
                    FROM    `Votes` 
                    WHERE   `postID` = `Posts`.`postID` 
                    LIMIT   1
                ) 
                + 0 
                * 5
            )
        ) AS `rank` 
FROM    Posts
) tabX
```

Comment: Then try to set rank as a variable then pow it like that in second separate query. If even then you get this error, I give up.

Comment: One of the comments on my question already solved it though, I posted the solution I used above :)