# MySQL Query with dynamic SQL dies with Error "Commands out of sync"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, dynamic-sql

I have the following procudure for parsing a table with quite a number of columns.

```
## Prozedur Droppen
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ifob.uspCreateViewFromTable;

## Prozedur erstellen
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspCreateViewFromTable`(IN ViewName varchar(255), IN TableName varchar(255))
BEGIN

  -- DECLARE column varchar(500);
  DECLARE colname varchar(500);
  DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

  /*
  DECLARE column_cursor FOR SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = Tablename;
  */
  DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = Tablename;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  #View Droppen falls sie schon erstellt wurde
  SET @s = CONCAT('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ',ViewName);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  #temp table droppen falls schon vorhanden
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ifob.tmpcols;
  # temporäre Tabelle erstellen
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ifob.tmpcols(columnname varchar(1024), averg real) ENGINE=MEMORY;
  -- OPEN column_cursor
  OPEN column_cursor;
  read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH column_cursor INTO colname;
      SELECT colname;
      SET @c=CONCAT('INSERT ifob.tmpcols SELECT `',colname,'`, AVG(`',colname, '`) FROM ',TableName,' LIMIT 0,100');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @c;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE column_cursor;
  #SELECT * from tmpcols;
  #DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ifob.tmpcols;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the procedure it runs well for about 1 1/2 min (approx 40 columns" and the it quits with the error "commands out of sync".

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) tells me it's probably the result of executing a query without first retrieving the results from the previous query.

I wonder if the error remains after you commented out the statement `SELECT * from tmpcols` at the end. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583020/mysql-stored-procedure-caused-commands-out-of-sync) (*2nd answer*) suggests that a prepare/execute loop with a non-empty result set will cause a second result set stacked on top of the first.

Comment: @Frank: THX for your answer. I've tried to take out the SELECT but it has no effect. But I realized that the INSERT statement seems to run ansynchronous. I replaces the "SELECT column" by an SELECT * FROM tbltmpcols and I can see that there are less entrys than there should be. Also strange is the fact that I cannot run any query in workbench after running in this error unless I have restarted it.

Comment: Have you tried allocating and deallocating the cursor inside the loop?

Comment: If you recycle the cursor every iteration, it won't get into a state where the cursor has an unfetched result set and a pending query.

Comment: Can you give me a short example how this should look like in code?