# mysql capi "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: c++, mysql

I have some C++ code which is calling a stored procedure using the C libmysqlcleint library. I stored the procedure onto my database by running the below SQL code via a query on the MySQL Workbench app.

Whenever my C++ code tries to call the stored sql procedure more than once, the query fails with a "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error. I've trimmed my code down to the simplest form which shows this error.

Here is the stored SQL procedure I am trying to run:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    SET @statement = CONCAT("SELECT 1"); 
    PREPARE command FROM @statement;
    EXECUTE command;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE command;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And here is my C++ code which tries to repeatedly call this procedure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

int main() {
    MYSQL sql;
    mysql_init(&sql);
    mysql_real_connect(&sql, "localhost", "password", "my-db", 0, NULL, 0); 
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        if(mysql_query(&sql, "CALL test()") == 0)  
            std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        else 
            std::cout << mysql_error(&sql) << std::endl;
    }
    mysql_close(&sql);
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
OK
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I've seen in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583020/mysql-stored-procedure-caused-commands-out-of-sync?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) articles that this issue can be caused by the database returning multiple results (I only get 1 result) or the user not calling mysql_store_results (I am). I can call the stored procedure multiple times when using the mysql client cli without any issues. In my actual, not simplified app I need to used stored procedures.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I changed the example code above to be even simpler while still showing the problem and I also update the background of the issue to give more information.

Comment: Try removing `;` from query so it looks like `CALL STATISTICS()`

Comment: @KillzoneKid I tried removing the ';' from 'CALL STATISTICS();' but I still go the same results. I also tried removing the ';' from the 'END;' in my procedure but that didn't change the outcome either.